# How to install an older version of the "SQLite for Universal Windows Platform" SDK for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, uwp, win-universal-app

I specifically need version 3.9.2 (latest is 3.19.3).

In Visual Studio 2015, the Extensions and Updates tool doesn't give an option to select a version like in Nuget Packages.

The [SQLite page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) only has instructions to download the souce code, the binary or the ADO.Net code, and if I'm not mistaken what I need is the .vsix file of the specific version to install the SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here.

[sqlite-uap-3090200.vsix](http://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-uap-3090200.vsix)

Link of the older version of sqlite is removed from the download page, but you can download it if you know the name of .vsix.

Added - There are some rules about url and file names.

History:
https://www.sqlite.org/chronology.html

For example... To get the 3.17.0,

1. Check the release year from history page : you can find that 3.17 was released at 2017.
2. Filename : 3.17.0 ==> 3 17 00 00 ==> 3170000.vsix
3. uap or uwp ? : From ver 3.11, the prefix was changed to 'uwp'. 3.10.2 or prior was 'uap'.
4. You got it! ... [http://www.sqlite.org/"2017"/sqlite-"uwp"-"3170000".vsix](http://www.sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-uwp-3170000.vsix)

Comment: I think people would appreciate if you could tell us the logic behind the numbers, I need v3.17.0 but sqlite-uap-3170000.vsix doesn't seem to work